# jquery doesn't seem to load after loading the page in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi im having a problem with the page loading another page i have a page a and page b with page a it has an ajax that loads page b ,and page b loads and runs jquery perfectly until i click on page a and then the jquery in page b doesnt seem to can anyone help me with this?

AJAX

```
function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                return new XMLHttpRequest(); //Not IE
            } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //IE
                alert("Your browser doesn't support the         XmlHttpRequest object.  Better upgrade to Firefox.");
            }
        }   


var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();     
        function get() {
            if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {
                receiveReq.open("GET", 'b.php', true);
                receiveReq.onreadystatechange = handleGet; 
                receiveReq.send(null);
            }           
        }
        function handleGet() {
            if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = receiveReq.responseText;
            }
        }
```

PAGE 1 THAT LOADS THE AJAX AND THE SECOND PAGE

```
<script src="add.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:get()">Live Chat</a>
<div id='content' class='content'></div>
```

PAGE 2 THAT THE PAGE 1 LOADS WITH THE WORKING JQUERY IF LOADED BY IT SELF BUT DOESNT WORK AFTER THE AJAX LOADS THIS PAGE

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Test selctions</title>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#' + $('#selection option:selected').text().toLowerCase()).show();
                $('#selection').change(function () {
                    $('.op').hide();
                    $('#' + $('#selection option:selected').text().toLowerCase()).show();
                });
                });
                </script>

                <style type="text/css">
                    #plane ,#boat,#car ,#other {
                display: none;
            }
                </style>

                </head>
                <body>

                options:
                <select id='selection'>
                <option>Pls choose</option>
                <option value='1' id='1'>Car</option>
                <option value='2' id='2'>Plane</option>
                <option value='3' id='3'>Boat</option>
                <option value=''>Other</option>

                </select><div>
                <div id='car' class='op'>you have chosen a car</div>
                <div id='plane' class='op'>you have chosen a plane</div>
                <div id='boat' class='op'>you have chosen a boat</div>
                <div id='other' class='op'>others</div>
            </div>





                </body>
            </html>
```

Can someone help me with this one and we would really appreciate it! and thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'AJAX LOADS THE PAGE'? I don't see code for the actual 'get' function (add.js is also mysterious). Why do you not use jquery for that part also?

Comment: its on the second code and also how can i do that in jquery? thanks!

Comment: it works perfectly in jquery thanks again!

Comment: Cool, glad you got that settled!

Answer (score -2):

Use live() or $(document).on() function of jquery.

**write all jquery function of page2 on page1 and use live() or $(document).on() functions.**

it will work...

Comment: You're not talking about the jQuery's `.live()` function are you?

Comment: I know live() is deprecated. but you can use $(document).on().

Comment: if i use that would it be secure?

Comment: Yes, it will be secure.! you can use it.

Comment: @prytsh It isn't just deprecated, it's __gone__.